# OSX App Bundle breaks paths within MONO app

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, bundle

I've stumbled upon a really odd problem that I can't find anything about in google. I've made a small Windows Forms app that works just fine on Windows and on OSX, but whenever the app must use some sort of path (to find app.config or to get the path of the executable), it returns a broken path, and this only happens when the .exe is embedded within an App bundle (folder with .app extension which consists of the Contents/MacOS and Contents/Resources subfolders). The actual executable being run when the user double clicks on the .app is just a script that pretty much goes "mono app.exe".

Here's an example of what I mean. Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location on different systems:

**Windows:** C:\Apps\Example.exe

**OSX when running it through the terminal manually with 'mono example.exe':** /Test/Folder/Structure/App.exe

**OSX when the .exe is run from within an .app:** /Test/Folder/Structure\App.exe

Because of this, I can't even get the in-built .NET/Mono functions to work, like, for example, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IconPath"] returns the correct data outside of .app, but from within it, it is empty (can't find the file probably).

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Here's the script that gets run when the user double-clicks on .app:

```
#!/bin/sh

#get the bundle's MacOS directory full path
DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)

#change these values to match your app
EXE_PATH="$DIR\MonoTests.exe"
PROCESS_NAME=MonoTestsProcess
APPNAME="Mono GUI Tests"

#set up environment
MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$DIR:$MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/lib:/lib:/usr/lib"
export PATH="$MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/bin:$PATH"

#mono version check
REQUIRED_MAJOR=2
REQUIRED_MINOR=4

VERSION_TITLE="Cannot launch $APPNAME"
VERSION_MSG="$APPNAME requires the Mono Framework version $REQUIRED_MAJOR.$REQUIRED_MINOR or later."
DOWNLOAD_URL="http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html"

MONO_VERSION="$(mono --version | grep 'Mono JIT compiler version ' |  cut -f5 -d\ )"
MONO_VERSION_MAJOR="$(echo $MONO_VERSION | cut -f1 -d.)"
MONO_VERSION_MINOR="$(echo $MONO_VERSION | cut -f2 -d.)"
if [ -z "$MONO_VERSION" ] \
    || [ $MONO_VERSION_MAJOR -lt $REQUIRED_MAJOR ] \
    || [ $MONO_VERSION_MAJOR -eq $REQUIRED_MAJOR -a $MONO_VERSION_MINOR -lt $REQUIRED_MINOR ] 
then
    osascript \
    -e "set question to display dialog \"$VERSION_MSG\" with title \"$VERSION_TITLE\" buttons {\"Cancel\", \"Download...\"} default button 2" \
    -e "if button returned of question is equal to \"Download...\" then open location \"$DOWNLOAD_URL\""
    echo "$VERSION_TITLE"
    echo "$VERSION_MSG"
    exit 1
fi

#get an exec command that will work on the current OS version
OSX_VERSION=$(uname -r | cut -f1 -d.)
if [ $OSX_VERSION -lt 9 ]; then  # If OSX version is 10.4
    MONO_EXEC="exec mono"
else
    MONO_EXEC="exec -a \"$PROCESS_NAME\" mono"
fi

#create log file directory if it doesn't exist
LOG_FILE="$HOME/Library/Logs/$APPNAME/$APPNAME.log"
mkdir -p "`dirname \"$LOG_FILE\"`"

#run app using mono

$MONO_EXEC $MONO_OPTIONS "$EXE_PATH" $* 2>&1 1> "$LOG_FILE"
```

OSX version is Maverick, I think.